# Access OSGI bundle context in application

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to access to the context of OSGI bundle in a java application to obtain a running service.

```
ctx.getServiceReference(ReceiverService.class.getName());
```

I tried with this:

```
BundleContext ctx = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ReceiverService.class).getBundleContext();
```

but it returns null

I init Knopflerfish in graphic mode with preinstalled bundles, and I start the SenderSevice bundle and the ReceiveService bundle. I want to access to ReceiveService to use the received objects in Java application. So I need to access to the ReceiveService bundle context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the ReceiveService interface loaded from? Is it exported from a bundle? Unfortunately the system bundle cannot import packages from ordinary bundles.

Since you are embedding OSGi, and communicating in terms of services between the outer application and the inner framework, the interfaces packages must be loaded by the outer application and exported using the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` property. This property is passed via the Map that you provide to `FrameworkFactory.newFramework()`. Then the ordinary bundles can import the service interface and publish the service.

To access a `BundleContext` from the outer application you must use the `getBundleContext()` method on the `Framework` object. This returns the `BundleContext` of the system bundle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, then I have to embed Osgi in my application with FrameworkFactory.newFramework(). If I used this, I charged a new framework, is there any way to charge my another configured Knopflerfish framework, or I have to installed all the bundles in the new framework?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to express better. Now, I init knopflerfish in graphic mode, so I have already installed bundles. If I use FrameworkFactory.newFramework(), I don't have any bundle installed. Is there any way to charge the configuration of the other Knopflerfish (graphic mode), or I have to install all the bundles again in the java application?

Comment: If you start a the framework with the same storage directory (`org.osgi.framework.storage` property) then it will start with the same set of bundles in the same state.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using an OSGi framework embedded in a Java application - how did you start that framework?

The standard way would be

```
Framework framework = FrameworkFactory.newFramework(props);
```

Then you can get the system bundle context from the `framework` instance:

```
BundleContext ctx = framework.getBundleContext();
```

In your example, `ReceiverService` was most likely loaded by the application classloader and not by a bundle classloader, so `FrameworkUtil` cannot determine the bundle that loaded this class.

Comment: I init Knopflerfish in graphic mode with preinstalled bundles, and I start the SenderSevice bundle and the ReceiveService bundle. I want to access to ReceiveService to use the received objects in Java application. So I need to access to the ReceiveService bundle context. It's the right way?